# facing problem in creating ireport with xml file as datasource in struts 2

Tags: struts2, ireport

Hello friends I am trying to create Report using ireport using xpath dataSource in struts 2 but when i execute action its working properly my report format is also comming properly but contains null value

**Here is my action class**

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
        Connectionhandler.establishConnection();
        ForReports fr = new ForReports();
        //Creating Servlet Context
        ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
        //Creating Source XML file
        fr.getFinalResult(Connectionhandler.con, (2009 + stmtYear), empId, context);
        Connectionhandler.closeConnection();
        try {
        // adding parameters
        reportParams.put("imgPath", context.getRealPath("/images"));
        //Contains Report Query
        reportParams.put("REPORT_QUERY", "/main/employee/nomineelst/nominee");

        //Compiling Report
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(
                context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/org/gea/report/pf/pfStatement.jrxml"),
                context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/org/gea/report/pf/pfStatement.jasper"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

**Here is Configuration for report in Struts.xml**

```
<action name="getReport" class="org.gea.action.pf.GenerateReport">
            <result name="success" type="jasper">
                <param name="location">/WEB-INF/classes/org/gea/report/pf/pfStatement.jasper</param>
                <param name="dataSource">"/WEB-INF/classes/org/gea/report/pf/PfStatementXML.xml"</param>
                <param name="format">PDF</param>
                <param name="reportParameters">reportParams</param>
                <param name="documentName">PF Statement</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Please help me in setting up this problem.

Comment: Did you fill report with parameters?

Comment: in reportParams one contains path for image and one contains parametr which is used as report query

Comment: yap i did it i did it in simple mvc its woring fine but not working with struts 2

Comment: Whatever i have done is correct Alex or not??

Comment: You don't publish class declaration therefore I thought that you forgot to pass parameter.

Comment: so Dave will u pls sugges me how to do it?? because m new in struts 2 so its littlbit defficult for me

Answer (score 1):

The `dataSource` element is expected to be an EL expression that exposes value stack data to the report, as per the [JasperReports Plugin docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/jasperreports-plugin.html).

If you're attempting to fill/run the report in some other way, it's not appropriate to use the plugin. The plugin is specifically meant to take data directly from a Struts 2 action and expose it to JasperReports without any intermediate steps.